# Married and two beautiful girls

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

I recently saw someone write

> Married and two beautiful girls

when he meant that he was married and had two children (girls).

I would have rather have written "*Married with two beautiful girls*" which for a non-native speaker seems really weird (at least in France and the other languages I know more or less) but I know this is the correct wording in English to indicate that you have two children (girls) and not that you practice polygamy.

This said, does "Married and two beautiful girls" **immediately** conveys the message "I am married and I have two children (girls)"?

I would like to stress the "immediately" part - that is the reaction of a native speaker to this sentence, without analyzing it in details. The correctness of the phrase is also interesting (I do not think it is really correct), though the perceived meaning is more important to me.

Comment: The way that's phrased makes it sound like a profile for an online app (Facebook, LinkedIn, whatever) where the writer is trying to be as succinct as possible.  It's almost headlinese.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the phrase ***Married and two beautiful girls*** immediately conveys the message "I am married and have two children (girls). Although, you are right and ***Married with two beautiful girls*** would have been a better way to structure the phrase.

Comment: But *married and two beautiful girls* is ungrammatical and also sounds awkward. To me, as a native speaker, I would not understand the sentence immediately. I would pause and say, "What?" In fact, the most likely interpretation is not that they are married *with* two girls but that they are married—and there happen to be two girls, somewhere, who may or may not be related to the speaker.

Comment: @JasonBassford - Yeah, but it's not a complete sentence anyway, so I feel like it's a little unfair to try and read it in isolation.  As a response to "What's your family situation?" it would be completely understandable, idiomatically.

Comment: @stangdon In considering this, I was thinking of the TV show *Married with Children*. That was understandable. A TV show named *Married and Children* would not have been.

Comment: Ungrammatical or not, the meaning is clear enough to me, so I'd have to agree with this answer. When I saw the question title on the questions page, the meaning I expected was exactly what was explained in OP's question; I came here to see if it was more complicated than that, but nope. (Native AmE speaker here.)